# Airflow FileSensor cannot sensor a file that exists

Tags: linux, airflow

A file sensor task I run on a daily bases failed this morning. I found the target file sitting there, so I ran the task again. However, it kept poking for the file until the sensor timed out. Then I tried running it a couple of times, but it just kept failing.

I'm sure the directory is accessible by my DAG. Could anyone help me out here please? A file sitting there but Airflow FileSensor just cannot sensor it.

Thank you.

Comment: did you fine any solutions for the issue. I am running into same issue